# Visual studio code - regex - edit multiple line?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I want to use visual studio code regex to introduce commas and single quote at different point of a line. Can you help please?
I want to transform

```
(1 ant 18 0 test abacus123 789 pass),
(2 dog 26 67 exp b+45 456 fail),
(3 tiger 5 2 'reg e-t' 126 fail),
```

To

```
(1, 'ant', 18, 0, 'test abacus123', 789, 'pass'),
(2, 'dog', 26, 67, 'exp b+45', 456, 'fail'),
(3, 'tiger', 5, 2, 'reg e-t', 126, 'fail'),
```

There are so many lines of data that i have to transform like this, not sure how to do it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If u are satisfied by a response, don't forget to up vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide more examples or describe the rules better.

According to the examples you have provided so far, you may try the following regex:

- Regex

```
\((\d+) '?(.+?)'? (\d+) (\d+) '?(.+?)'? (\d+) '?(\w+)'?\)
```

- Substitution

```
($1, '$2', $3, $4, '$5', $6, '$7')
```

Check the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/mOdZ0f/1/)